# LaTeX Error: `xcolor.sty' not found when including tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

my preamble is currently looking like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
```

When I include

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

I get the error message
    ! LaTeX Error: File `xcolor.sty' not found.

I have tried to \include{xcolor} before and after tikz which didn't work. Also from another post I have seen that I should \PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor} before declaring the document class. Whatever I do I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

In Ubuntu 22.04 I solved installing `texlive-latex-recommended`:

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-recommended
```

Answer (score -1):

In `MikTeX` this package may be located here: `\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty`. If not, please download xcolor.sty and put it into your working directory or, better, the whole package xcolor.

Also try to to use the package `xcolor`:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```